# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type .

Tags: reactjs, typescript, database, react-typescript

I have been trying to run this React Typescript App, but it keeps getting this error, and I have no idea what to do!
2 errors states:

"Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly': isAdmin, username, history, location, match"

This here would be the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  username: string;
}

interface IState {
  posts: IPost[];
  comments: IComment[];
}

interface IPost {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  author: string;
}

interface IComment {
  id: number;
  postId: number;
  body: string;
  author: string;
}

class Website extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      comments: [],
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPosts();
    this.fetchComments();
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.isAdmin && (
          <div>
            <Link to="/create-post">Create Post</Link>
            <Link to="/delete-post">Delete Post</Link>
          </div>
        )}
        {this.props.username && (
          <div>
            <Link to="/create-comment">Create Comment</Link>
            <Link to="/edit-comment">Edit Comment</Link>
            <Link to="/delete-comment">Delete Comment</Link>
          </div>
        )}
        <div>
          {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <h2>{post.title}</h2>
              <p>{post.body}</p>
              <p>By: {post.author}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.comments.map((comment) => (
            <div key={comment.id}>
              <p>{comment.body}</p>
              <p>By: {comment.author}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  private createPost = (title: string, body: string) => {
    // Create a new post in the database
  };

  private deletePost = (id: number) => {
    // Delete the post with the specified id from the database
  };

  private createComment = (postId: number, body: string) => {
    // Create a new comment in the database
  };

  private editComment = (id: number, body: string) => {
    // Edit the comment with the specified id in the database
  };

  private deleteComment = (id: number) => {
    // Delete the comment with the specified id from the database
  };

  private fetchPosts = () => {
    // Fetch posts from the database and update the state
  };

  private fetchComments = () => {
    // Fetch comments from the database and update the state
  };
}

export default Website;
```

I really dont know where to fix it.

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand `RouteComponentProps` is extended as a generic, so you pass it a type representing the path parameters you want .e.g

```
interface PathParams {
  id: string
}

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<PathParams> {...}
```